# Is there a .NET equivalent to CoCreateInstanceEx?

Tags: .net, com

The closest thing I've found is using Activator.CreateInstance, but you can't pass it a server name/account information.

What I would like to do is programmatically create a COM object on a different computer. (I know I can create it on a different computer by manipulating the component properties in the control panel, but I want to start the COM component on a different server dynamically, based on a user choice)

Is there a managed way to this, or should I p-invoke CoCreateInstanceEx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you will need to use `CoCreateInstanceEx` via P/Invoke.

Comment: If that's the case, then why there is 'server' parameter in 'GetTypeFromCLSID'? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y76yy1s2(v=vs.100).aspx